# Can't get div / section to appear over responsive img element

Tags: html, css, image, absolute

I'm having a couple of issues with the following code. Idea is to have a row of three images, each one contained in its' own section tag and then have another section to appear directly over it. Really, two problems here as the category-link isn't aligning centered but rather left and also, the div is appearing beneath the img and not over it. It's responsive, so I can't just set a fixed height into it and I already tried height: 100%; to the section feature-third, to no avail. That being said, here's the code I'm using now:

First the HTML:

```
 <section class="feature-third fade-in two">
 <a href="#" title="">
 <img width="960" height="960" src="img.jpg" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="" />
 <section class="feature-caption"><p class="category-link">Category Name</p>    <h2>Title of Article</h2></section>
 </a>
 </section>
```

Now the CSS:

```
.feature-third { float: left; width: 33.333%; color: #FFF; overflow: hidden; display: block; }
.feature-third a img { opacity: 1; transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s; }
.feature-third a:hover img, .feature-third a:hover img { opacity: 0.75; transform: scale(1.1, 1.1); }
.feature a, .feature-third a { color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; }
.feature-third .feature-caption {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.feature-third .feature-caption .category-link {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    min-width: 90px;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide a demo (jsfiddle.net). I'm not able to replicate the problem you're describing with the code above.

Comment: I tried doing it in CodePen, but couldn't get it to appear the same way on my own site. So I made an HTML example stripping out a lot of the code I'm currently not using to show this effect: https://thecleverroot.com/feature-third.html

Comment: So you want the category links ("post") to appear centered and above the images?

Comment: Micheal, I want the entire feature-caption div to appear above the image. Not just the category links although that is certainly part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Im unable to work out the problem with your code, maybe there was somethign I did not understand.
But based on your code, I made a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5p2pztqr/

I did not understand the purpose of adding the width here:

```
.feature-third { 
    width: 33.333%; 
}
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: That's simple to answer. There's going to be three .featured-third div's. Each one contains an image and the caption on a single row (for desktop and tablets) so that's why the width is 33.333%. To get as close to 100% as possible.

Comment: So in your example, you have a div called #featured with a fixed with of 960px width and 200px height. No good. Must be 100% width and the height is flexible and will change based on the height of the three images.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Here's the new code I used to make it work.

First I swapped the positioning the HTML of the caption and the image:

```
 <section class="feature-third fade-in two">
 <a href="#" title="">
 <section class="feature-caption"><p class="category-link">Category Name</p>    <h2>Title of Article</h2></section>
 <img width="960" height="960" src="img.jpg" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="" />
 </a>
 </section>
```

Then made these changes in the CSS:

Then added position:relative to my feature-third columns:

```
body.home .feature-third { position: relative; float: left; width: 33.333%; color: #FFF; overflow: hidden; display: block; }
```

That worked!